# How to get calendar change events? Is calendar observer working?

Tags: android

I want to receive the calendar change events on android device. I try to register a observer for it, but it's not working.

Do I have to retrieve all the events periodically to know something is changed?

Here're my codes, appreciate for any response.

```
public class CalendarObserver extends ContentObserver 
{
    public CalendarObserver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
    }

    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.i("", "Calendar changes");
    }
}
```

Register it on my main activity, but it's not working.

```
CalendarObserver observer = new CalendarObserver (new Handler());
getContentResolver().notifyChange(
    Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), observer);
```

---

Also tried ..., but still not working

```
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id"};
Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
//Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
//Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);
cursor.registerContentObserver(observer);
```

---

Also tried to use the intent receiver,  because I saw the following log from logcat,
but it's still not working.

```
 I/CalendarProvider2(13444): Sending notification intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://com.android.calendar }
```

...

```
 CalendarReceiver receiver= new CalendarReceiver ();
 filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED");
 registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code,

```
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id" };
Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");

Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, projection, null, null, null);
```

and then use [registerContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#registerContentObserver%28android.database.ContentObserver%29) to monitor the Cursor for changes.